# Magento 2.1.6 inodes are 100%

Tags: magento2, magento-2.1, magento2.1.6

I did the resize images command due to the bug in 2.1.6 and now the inodes are way over my quota and the images are not fully loaded yet.
Is there anything we can do to solve this ASAP.

I have been clearing my cache every 3-4 hours to make sure the site does not crash.

Answer (score 0):

The Magento strongly recommend that you upgrade to 2.1.7 as soon as that release is available. Magento 2.1.7 will contain a fix for this issue as well as critically important security enhancements. They provide the hotfix described in this Technical Bulletin as a temporary fix only.

You can fix this issue with image resizing by downloading and installing the `CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch` hotfix, and then immediately upgrading to Magento 2.1.7, as soon as it is available.

To download this patch,

1) On [Magento Tech Resources](https://magento.com/tech-resources/download), choose **Downloads > Magento Community Edition Patches > 2.x**.

2) Select the `CE-MAGETWO-67805.patch` hotfix.

> For further discussion of this issue, see [GITHUB-9385](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9385) and [GITHUB-9395](https://github.com/magento/magento2/issues/9395)

[Reference on DevDocs.](http://devdocs.magento.com/guides/v2.1/release-notes/tech_bull_216-imageresize.html)

Comment: Im already aware of that.
How do I install that patch?